# Use ready-made character class and restrict it further

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

Lots of ready-to-use character classes are available in Perl regular expressions, such as `\d` or `\S`, or new-fangled Unicode grokkers such as [`\p{P}`, which matches punctuation characters](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html).

Now let's say I'd like to match all punctuation characters `\p{P}` (quite a number of them, and not something you want to type in by hand) - all but one, all but the good old komma (or comma, `,`).

Is there a way to specify this requirement short of expanding the handy character class and taking away the komma by hand?

Comment: Found a very similar question, well, basically the same question: [How to match any non white space character except a particular one in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6125137/269126)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ unichars -au '\p{P}' | wc -l
598
```

Double negation:

```
/[^\P{P},]/

$ unichars -au '[^\P{P},]' | wc -l
597
```

"And" through lookahead/lookbehind:

```
/\p{P}(?<!,)/

$ unichars -au '\p{P}(?<!,)' | wc -l
597
```

[`unichars`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/unichars)

Comment: Great, thanks! Also very useful: your link to the `unichars` script.

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
[^\P{P},]
```

This is a negated character class, that matches all but the listed characters.

`\P{P}` negated `\p{P}`